# What does the following statement do?

Tags: c#

I'm not a c# programmer at all, but need to get certain calculations from a C# app. No I ran into something that I'm not sure if what the output is

I have the following line of code

```
pageSizeFactor = PrintingRequirements.FormSize == FormSize.A4 ? 1 : 2;
```

I just need to confirm if I am correct, the above means the following, pageSizeFactor = the Formsize, so if the Formsize is A4 pageSizeFactor will be 1 else it will be 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; if `PrintingRequirements.FormSize` is `FormSize.A4`, `pageSizeFactor` will be 1. Otherwise, it will be 2.

That operator (`?:`) is known as [the conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty67wk28.aspx). It is also sometimes known as the ternary operator. Its syntax goes like this:

```
a ? b : c
```

If `a` evaluates to `true`, the result will be `b`; otherwise, it will be `c`.

Comment: thank you for this, answers my question perfectly, since the app has many of these expressions.

Answer (score 5):

That is the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
result = boolean-expression ? expression-if-true : expression-if-false
```

Essentially `if - else` inline.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to write the code you provided is:

```
if (PrintingRequirements.FormSize == FormSize.A4){
    pageSizeFactor =  1;
} else {
    pageSizeFactor =  2;
}
```